# Различия в выводе file и binwalk

Tags: linux, xdebug, mips

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему различается вывод по структуре файла, между binwalk и file. Binwalk говорит что это Elf 32, mips64, а file, что это elf 32 mips 32-bit.

Comment: Наверное, различие в алгоритмах работы. Может ошибка где. Без файла сказать кто прав нельзя, как и уверенно ответить в чем дело в конкретном случае.

Comment: Ок, вечерком залью. Просто необходимо понимать под какую систему компилировать gdbserver.

Comment: А смысл заливать? Описание формата ELF берите и смотрите где там архитектура указана

Comment: Не совсем понял причём здесь Elf. У mips процессоров разная архитектура ( mips-1,2,32,64). А эти двое говорят по разному.

Comment: Вывод "elf" из обоих утилит вас не смутил?

Comment: Имеется ввиду просто открыть и посмотреть что указано в файле на прямую? Так, а file разве не этим занимается?

Comment: Так а вы не думаете что кто-то из двух софтин ошибается и вы не знаете кто?

Comment: > Не совсем понял причём здесь Elf. У mips процессоров разная архитектура --



By design, ELF is flexible, extensible, and cross-platform, not bound to any given central processing unit (CPU) or instruction set architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Всё, разобрался. Readelf даёт более точную информацию. 
PS gdbserver успешно запустился на целевой системе.
Всем спасибо.